# Transaction Management with Raw SQL and Models in a single transaction Django 1.11.49

Tags: django, database, django-models, transactions

I have an API which reads from two main tables Table A and Table B.

Table A has a column which acts as foreign key to Table B entries.

Now inside api flow, I have a method which runs below logic.

1. Raw SQL -> Joining table A with some other tables and fetching entries which has an active status in Table A.
2. From result of previous query we take the values from Table A column and fetch related rows from Table B using Django Models.

It is like

```
query = "Select * from A where status = 1"  #Very simplified query just for example
cursor = db.connection.cursor()
cursor.execute(query)
results = cursor.fetchAll()

list_of_values = get_values_for_table_B(results)
b_records = list(B.objects.filter(values__in=list_of_values))
```

Now there is a background process which will enter or update new data in Table A and Table B. That process is doing everything using models and utilizing

```
with transaction.atomic():
     do_update_entries()
```

However, the update is not just updating old row. It is like deleting old row and deleting related rows in Table B and then new rows are added to both tables.

Now the problem is if I run api and background job separately then everything is good, but when both are ran simultaneously then for many api calls the second query of Table B fails to get any data because the transaction executed in below manner:

```
Table A RAW Transaction executes and read old data
Background Job runs in a single txn and delete old data and enter new data. Having different foreign key values that relates it to Table B.
Table B Models read query executes which refers to values already deleted by previous txn, hence no records
```

So, for reading everything in a single txn I have tried below options

```
with transaction.atomic():
     # Raw SQL for Table A
     # Models query for Table B
```

This didn't worked and I am still getting same issue.

I tried another way around

```
transaction.set_autocommit(False)
Raw SQl for Table A
Models query for Table B
transaction.commit()
transaction.set_autocommit(True)
```

But this didn't work either. How can I read both queries in a single transaction so background job updates should not affect this read process.

Comment: Do you need to use raw SQL, could you use the ORM instead? If you have a foriegn key from Table A to Table B you could fetch the related data from Table B in the same query with a join

Comment: @IainShelvington Can't use ORM as using a complex join query in actual case as ORM fetch is slow for all involved tables.

Comment: Which database are you using? The ORM should not be significantly slower, can you add your models and raw SQL? Row locks may help - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#select-for-update https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-locking-reads.html

Comment: @IainShelvington I am using MySQL. The fetch using ORM is causing delay of few seconds but that is where my NFR SLAs are breaching and will not suit my use-case. I can't post the models and raw sql as it is company's intellectual property. select_for_update() will not work as I can't lock the complete table B and filter could only be possible once I get results from raw sql query. Regarding row locks, they will not work as well as they are still creating 2 different transaction for raw sql and models query, which will give a chance to background job transaction to sneak between them.